# How to give responsive title in ion-header-bar in ionic framework based on selected page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In header bar I need title to change dynamically according to current page app is on. It can be achieved using ion-nav-bar but I also need my custom controls on bar along with fixed header bar for all pages.

So in {{pageTitle}} variable is used for title attribute in header bar, I want to know where and how or in which controller can I create and update this variable, so change is reflected whenever page is navigated?

```js
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">{{pageTitle}}</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  Some content!
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable `pageTitle` in `$rootScope`:

```
angular.module('your_app_name', [])
.run(funtion($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.pageTitle = 'Something initial';
});
```

and change `$rootScope.pageTitle` in template's controller whenever you need change page title:

```
angular.module('your_app_name')
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.pageTitle = 'Another Title';
});
```